# How to show global messages in Magento 1.9 admin as latest Message by using front end

Tags: php, forms, magento, magento-1.9

How to show global messages in Magento 1.9 admin as latest message by using front end.

```
<form action = "index.php" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "mymsg" />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 ??code??
}
?>
```

When I click on submit it has to send a message and show on admin panels global message area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not a few things to hook into the `notifications` area.

*Note: in the following I'm only touching on the files and parts needed to make messages appear in the global notification area. This is not enough to make a complete extension. Seek that information elsewhere. A good start is [Silk Module Creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)*

You'll need reference `notifications` area with a block in your extensions *layout file*.

#### File structure

These are the files we are going to cover below:

```
app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php     
app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Model/Notification.php
app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Model/Observer.php
design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/yourcompany/yourextension.xml
```

#### Config: app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/etc/config.xml

As everything else it starts in your `config.xml`. You'll probably already have block- and model-section defined for your extension, but I've included them here for completion.

The important part to notice is the reference to the layout file and the observer we'll setup to listen for messages:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Yourcompany_Yourextension>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Yourcompany_Yourextension>
    </modules>
    <global>
        ...
        <blocks>
            <yourextension>
                <class>Yourcompany_Yourextension_Block</class>
            </yourextension>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <yourextension>
                <class>Yourcompany_Yourextension_Model</class>
            </yourextension>
        </models>
        <events>
            <yourextension_notifications_before>
                <observers>
                    <yourextension_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Yourcompany_Yourextension_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkMessages</method>
                    </yourextension_observer>
                </observers>
            </yourextension_notifications_before>
        </events>

        ...
    <adminhtml>
        ...
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <yourextension>
                    <file>yourcompany/yourextension.xml</file>
                </yourextension>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        ...
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

#### Layout: design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/yourcompany/yourextension.xml

In the layout file you'll have to make a reference to the notification area. It is simply called `notifications`.

The `<default>` is the path for which this layout is to be used. `<default>` means everywhere.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="notifications">
            <block type="yourextension/adminhtml_notifications" name="notifications_yourcompany" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

The block part type is string that lets Magento look up the block.

```
<block type="yourextension/adminhtml_notifications" name="notifications_yourcompany" />
```

The first part `yourextension` obviously tells it to look in your extension path: `app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension`

The second part `adminhtml_notifications` turns into: `Adminhtml/Notifications.php`

These two parts are glued together by `Block` and your have, viola: `app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Block/Adminhtml/Notifications.php`

The name in `<block name="yourextension"/>` just have to be unique.

#### app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Block/Notifications.php

In this example the block will get the data and render the HTML directly. Normally you would include a template as well, but for this it is not necessary.

To get the messages we use an oberserver-pattern. This means that we send out a message that we about to write out the notifications. This means that other parts of the extension or even other extensions can opt to add messages.

This is `Mage::dispatchEvent('yourextension_notifications_before')` part below.

If another part of the extension listens to this event and adds messages to our Notification model, then we are in luck. In fact we already know from `config.xml` that our `Observer` model will listen to this event.

So when we call `getMessages()` on our `Notification` model below messages will have magically appeared.

The last part of the `_toHtml` is what renders the notifications.

```
class Yourcompany_Yourextension_Block_Adminhtml_Notifications extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function _toHtml($className = "notification-global")
    {
        // Let other extensions add messages
        Mage::dispatchEvent('yourextension_notifications_before');
        // Get the global notification object
        $messages = Mage::getSingleton('yourextension/notification')->getMessages();
        $html = null;
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            $html .= "<div class='$className'>" . $message . "</div>";
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

#### Model: app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Model/Notification.php

The model is super simple for our purpose. Think of the `Notification` model as a container for messages rather than a single notification.

```
class Yourcompany_Yourextension_Model_Notification extends Varien_object
{
    protected $messages = [ ];

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    public function setMessages($messages)
    {
        $this->messages = $messages;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addMessage($message)
    {
        $this->messages[] = $message;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### Observer (sender): app/code/local/Yourcompany/Youextension/Model/Observer.php

The observer is the last piece of the magic. We set it up in `config.xml` to listen for `yourextension_notifications_before`. So when our block is about to render we have the option to add a message to the Notification model first.

```
class Yourcompany_Yourextension_Model_Observer
{

    public function checkMessages($observer)
    {
        $notifications = Mage::getSingleton('yourextension/notification');
        $notifications->addMessage("I was sent by Yourextension");
        return $observer;
    }
}
```

#### Wrap up

So once you extension boots up it registers `Model/Observer` to listen for a certain event—the event that we are about to render notifications.

We have created a layout that references Magento's own notification area and on all pages we will render our own block.

The since `Model\Notification` is a singleton we can `addMessage()`s to it from all over our extension (and outside) and when we call `getMessages()` we'll get them all. We don't have to worry about storing multiple messages temporarily.

Like I started this answer, I'm assuming you area already working on a page with the form you included. You should have it set messages to `Notification` model as well.

It is up to you how you want to store the messages—in session or using a model resource to save in the database.